# Using reference type variables

Tags: powershell, pass-by-reference

It could be that it is nearly 5 pm on a Friday, but I am having trouble learning how to use `[ref]` type variables in PowerShell.

The following prints 'NotTest'

```
[ref]$refString = 'Test'
$string = $refString
$refString.Value = 'NotTest'
$string
```

Where I am confused is that the following doesn't print the new values for $a, $b or $c:

```
[ref]$a = 'test'
[ref]$b = 'foo'
[ref]$c = 'bar'
$arguments= "?arg1=" + $a.value + "&arg2=" + $b.value + "&arg3=" + $c.value

$a.Value = 'no'
$b.Value = 'change'
$c.Value = 'Happens'
$arguments
```

Is there a way to correctly reference the new values?

Comment: So you're creating a string composed of values of reference types then expecting that updating the reference types will also update the string which is immutable? Use commas to create an array instead of a string then it will update.

Comment: In your second example, the fact that ```$a```, ```$b``` and ```$c``` are ```[ref]``` variables is kind of irrelevant - the right-hand side of ```$arguments = …``` is evaluated using the values at *that point in time* and the result is a *string*, not a dynamic formula. When the instance values of ```$a```, ```$b``` and ```$c``` change, the string assigned to ```$arguments``` doesn’t get recalculated. Consider a similar program - ```$x = 1; $s = “value of x is “ + $x; $x = 2; write-host $s``` - what would you expect to be output to the console? (spoiler alert: “value of x is 1” :-))

Answer (score 0):

In your first example `$string` holds the same reference as `$refString` (a mutable type) whereas in your second example you're constructing a string (an immutable type) by concatenating strings with the **values** (also immutable strings) of your `PSReference`s, meaning that `$arguments` is immutable. Updating the values of the `PSReference` will not affect the already constructed string.

By the looks of what you have and a bit of guessing, I think [`UriBuilder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uribuilder?view=net-7.0) and [`HttpUtility.ParseQueryString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httputility.parsequerystring?view=net-7.0#system-web-httputility-parsequerystring(system-string)) is what you're after:

```
if (-not $IsCoreCLR) {
    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Web
}

$builder = [System.UriBuilder]::new('myurlhere')
$query = [System.Web.HttpUtility]::ParseQueryString('')
$query['args1'] = 'test'
$query['args2'] = 'foo'
$query['args3'] = 'bar'
$builder.Query = $query.ToString()
$builder.Uri.ToString()
# Outputs: http://myurlhere/?args1=test&args2=foo&args3=bar

$query['args1'] = 'changes'
$query['args2'] = 'happen'
$query['args3'] = 'here'
$builder.Query = $query.ToString()
$builder.Uri.ToString()
# Outputs: http://myurlhere/?args1=changes&args2=happen&args3=here
```